# How extensive is CD47?

Tags: cell-biology, gene-expression

CD47 aka the "don't eat me" signal has recently been claimed [to be expressed on all tumor cells](http://www.pnas.org/content/early/2012/03/20/1121623109.short). This doesn't seem to corroborate with other cell-biology experiments. On what other cells is CD47 expressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how extensive. Let's run a simple data query and find out: Go to [GEO](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/) at NCBI. In the "Gene profiles" window, type CD47, and hit enter to launch the query. At the top of the resulting page, use the link labeled "Limits" to restrict the 7000+ results to human by entering the term "human" in the "DataSet organism" window. So, there are 3700+ results. Look through them to get an idea of which cell types and under which conditions *CD47* is expressed.

Let's try a second method. Go to the [BioGPS](http://biogps.org) portal. Enter CD47 in the appropriate window and run the query. From the results, select the row with ID # 961 as this represents the human gene *CD47*. The resulting gene expression/activity chart for Hs (human) will show you in more general terms where *CD47* is expressed.

Answer (score 1):

I can't give a comprehensive answer to this, but the [CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_of_differentiation) proteins are found on white blood cells of various types.  If you think about it its impossible that a surface protein could be *only* observed on cancer cells as cancer is a cell line which is a reproductive dead end.   You can see on the geneatlas box on the lower right side of the page - its gene is expressed, at least to a small amount, on nearly every major tissue type.